# Numbers for OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, numbers

I need Numbers for OS X Yosemite. When I try to install from the [Apple store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825?mt=12&ls=1&v0=www-us-mac-numbers-app-numbers), it only gives the option for 4.1. I think I need 3.2.2 or around there.

When I try to install 4.1 it complains:

[image]

I cannot find any documentation or links for older versions of Numbers.

Looking for a downloadable/link for Numbers that works on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: Is updating your OS an option for you?

Comment: @bjbk It is but would rather just install a compatible version of Numbers since upgrading would break a lot of things

Comment: Understood. You may be able to find an old iWork DVD. But subsequent versions were distributed only via the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Searching [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com) for **iWork for OS X 10.10** turned up a [download link for iWork 9.3](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1563?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) however, from what I can tell, it may just be an update installer.  But searching Apple Support is a good place to start.  In order to use the App Store version, one would have to update to OS X 10.12 or higher as noted in the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks bjbk. I have the same problem, and your download link for iWork 9.3 installed Numbers version 2.3 (554) which looks like the whole package not just an update. It's newer than my previous Numbers v 2.0.5 (368) and seems to work okay...

Comment: download -> iWork_9.3_Update.dmg -> `400032515 Nov  8  2014 iWork_9.3_Update.pkg` -> "An eligible Keynote application was not found in the location /Applications/iWork '09." and doesn't install (on 10.10 yosemite).